# user always redirected to login on refresh in nuxt.js auth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app setup with @nuxt/auth. The user always get redirected to login page whenever the page is refreshed. I guess the server side of the Nuxt app is **not logged in** while the client side is **logged in**. The JWT access token is gotten from an Express API.  Please can someone help me to solve this?. Here is my nuxt.config.js

```
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: '/',
      home: '/dashboard',
    },
    resetOnError: true,
    rewriteRedirects: true,
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'data.accessToken',
        },
        user: {
          property: 'data[0]',
          autoFetch: false,
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/api/v1/users/login',
            method: 'post',
          },
          logout: false,
          user: {
            url: '/api/v1/users',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: false,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

And my dashboard.vue

```
export default {
  middleware: ['auth'],



};
```

Comment: You can add the middleware directly to your `nuxt.config.js` with `router: { middleware: ['auth'] }` and whitelist it per page with `export default { auth: false }`. On the main issue, do you have a `loggedIn` set to `true` in your `$auth` module ? This is the flag that got checked against the `@nuxt/auth` module to determine if you're actually logged-in or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. By default, the logged in flag in-store should be false. But after logging in through the log in form, the logged in flag is changed to true and persisted in localstorage with vuex-persistedState library.  I noticed that the when I console.log the state in the auth middleware I created, the logged in flag is false (I mean all the store values are in their default state) but the localstorage is having the correct store state. I sense the server side of the nuxt app is not aware of the state changes in the client side.

Comment: Since the pages are server-side generated. it picks and use the available default store values (at that moment) instead of the persisted store values in the localstorage

Comment: You created your own `auth` middleware ? The module is giving one itself, maybe there is a conflict here ? I'll post my config in an answer, if it can somehow help. Btw, I `yarn generate`'ed a project and it's totally fine on my side, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working `nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  router: {
    middleware: ['auth'],
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    home: '/',
    logout: '/login',
    callback: false, // not used here in our case
  },
  localStorage: false, // REALLY not secure, so nah
  resetOnError: true, // kick the user if any error happens w/ the auth
  strategies: {
    local: {
      scheme: 'refresh', // used for the refreshToken flow
      token: {
        property: 'access_token',
        maxAge: 3600, // only useful if not detected on the login
      },
      refreshToken: {
        property: 'refresh_token',
        data: 'refresh_token',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 1 month
      },
      clientId: process.env.IAM_CLIENT_ID, // our application's ID aka browser
      user: {
        property: 'employee',
        autoFetch: false, // no need to fetch the user, will be done in gql
      },
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/login', method: 'post' },
        refresh: { url: '/oauth/refresh', method: 'post' },
        user: false, // as told above, this one is not needed
        logout: { url: '/logout', method: 'get' },
      },
      tokenRequired: true,
      tokenType: 'JWT',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/nuxt-axios.js',
    { src: '~/plugins/nuxt-auth.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],
}
```

`nuxt-auth.js` is a basic logger in case of an error

```js
import $toast from '~/mixins/buefy-toast'

export default function ({ $auth }) {
  $auth.onError((_name, error) => {
    $toast.open({ message: error })
  })
}
```

Another important part is my login flow (triggered on a form submit)

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async authMe() {
      const succesfulLogin = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        },
      })
      if (succesfulLogin) {
        await this.$auth.setUser({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        })
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

We do basically not get the user on the API while authenticating, but rather submit the credentials and validate them, then setting the flag manually with the function `$auth.setUser`. This is the only part that I handle to pass the `loggedIn` flag to true, the remaining configuration is just project configuration.
We do also have some `refreshToken` on our JWT but you can totally omit this one.

Axios config file is basically setting our app's needed headers.

The `auth` middleware is the one coming w/ the `@nuxt/auth` module itself, I did not wrote it myself. This is totally working (cookies + vuex state) when generated with `target: 'static'`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of the node version, you can install version 16.9.1 and solve the error.

In my case, I had version 18.14.2 and it gave me the /login redirection error because when refreshing the page in SSR mode the server returned the $auth.loggedIn variable as false and mutated to true when I entered the client section. So the middleware always sent the login redirection rule.

In theory, you should add a section in nuxtServerInit to get the cookie that is stored in that variable and add it somewhere haha

But I really don't know if that can be done

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).